# Select data according to manager & employee level in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Table structure is like this -

id   Name  Manager
1    aa    NULL
2    hh    1
3    YY    4
4    Kk    NULL
5    PP    4

So I want the result like-

Name Manager
aa   NULL
hh   aa
Kk   NULL
YY   Kk
PP   Kk

Answer (score 1):

SELECT a.name AS employee, b.name AS manager
FROM `employees` AS a
JOIN employees AS b ON a.manager_id = b.id

This would work , will give you employee and its manager

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.name, a.name FROM table AS a RIGHT JOIN table AS b ON a.manager = b.id
```

Comment: I have tried this but I want to show manager first then their employee then second manager & then their employee.

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED** Try this:

```
SELECT Name FROM table ORDER BY IFNULL(Manager,id), IFNULL(Manager,0), Name
```

I *think* this would get you all the managers grouped together, with the managers being in front of their employees who should be sorted by name.  Unfortunately I can't get to a MySQL server instance at the moment to test.